# Mysql creating a view based on existing table

Tags: mysql

I have an excel sheet that I feed into the database as below each month:

[image]

The components are repeated each month. Is there a way I can create a view where I can see a monthly report of tyres based on the car brand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`Date`, '%Y-%m') year_month, 
       SUM(Toyota) Toyota, SUM(Nissan) Nissan, ...
FROM source_table
WHERE Components = 'Tyres'
GROUP BY 1
```